# Networked folder 'type to jump to folder' working sequentially on letters typed rather than searching for all letters typed

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search

I'm using Windows 10 pro 20H2.

If I search a folder on our file server, I usually type a few letters to bring up the folder I want, for example "LOR" to bring up "LOREM".

However I am seeing an issue on one PC where instead of this behavior, the search is working sequentially on the letters typed, jumping from all folders beginning "L", then "O", then "R". This occurs no matter what speed I type the letters at.

Does anyone know of a resolution for this issue?

Comment: Have you tried in file explorer going to `view > options > search` and reset to defaults?

Comment: Does it help if you single quote the search e.g. `'LOR'` then does it work correctly?

Comment: In the Search bar, try specifying the property to search on: `name:LOR` or maybe `name:="LOR*"`.

Comment: @lost_admin I have tried that to no effect I'm afraid.

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT I'm not using the search bar, just typing in the top level folder. Pressing ' does not allow me to type anything. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @KeithMiller I'm not using the search bar, just typing in the top level folder. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: The **Search** *bar* is to the right of the **Address** bar in an **Explorer** window, not the Taskbar/Start Menu Search. ***It is how a search is executed from Explorer!*** Are you even trying what's suggested? Do you realize there is a syntax involved?

Comment: Re-reading, I think you're talking about the behavior when typing while the manin pane of the the **Explorer** window has the focus - where pressing a single key repeatedly with a slight delay between each press moves from one item to the next, correct? Does pressing `L` , `L` move from `Label` to `Last`?

Answer (score 1):

1. To start, go to **Folder Options** | **View** tab | press <kbd>`Reset Folders`</kbd> and press <kbd>`Yes`</kbd> when prompted.

   [image]
2. Now go back to a folder, sort by `Name` by clicking on the <kbd>`Name`</kbd> column. Then go back to **Folder Options** | **View** tab | press <kbd>`Apply to Folders`</kbd> and press <kbd>`Yes`</kbd> when prompted here.

   [image]

Now try tying in and searching the folders and see if this does the trick. If not, see the **General Troubleshooting** section below for additional things I'd try. Once any of those are complete, you may or may not need to complete these steps again.

---

## General Troubleshooting

Consider the following in no particular order though...

- Run full antivirus and antimalware scans of your system
- Ensure all the latest Windows Updates are downloaded, installed, and any correlated reboots have completed too
- Run Windows 10 system health checks and cleanup scans

  > ```
  > SFC /SCANNOW
  > DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
  > DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /SPSuperseded
  > DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
  > ```
  >
  > **PowerShell Elevated**
  >
  > ```
  > Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\*' | % {
  >     New-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name StateFlags0001 -Value 2 -PropertyType DWord -Force
  > };
  > Start-Process -FilePath CleanMgr.exe -ArgumentList '/sagerun:1'
  > ```
- Run `chkdsk` for file system corruption  (e.g. admin elevated `chkdsk C: /f /r /x`)

I'd start with the basics here and rule these things out too just in case.